# cobertura-instrument does not seem to exclude classes from the jar

Tags: regex, ant, cobertura

I am new to cobertura and I am using ant directly to instrument the jars.

the build.xml looks like this:

```
    <cobertura-instrument   datafile="${jboss.dir}\cobertura.ser" >
<includeClasses regex=".*A.*"/>
<excludeClasses regex=".*B.*"/>

<fileset dir="${lib.dir}"> 
    <include name="*.jar"/>
</fileset>
```

The inclusion/exclusion doesnt seem to work at all as it is instrumenting all the classes.Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/anttaskreference.html) states there are two ways to do this.

A combination of an ignore statement with limited filesets:

```
<delete file="cobertura.ser" />

<cobertura-instrument todir="${instrumented.dir}">
    <ignore regex="org.apache.log4j.*" />
    <fileset dir="${classes.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.class" />
        <exclude name="**/*Test.class" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${jars.dir}">
        <include name="my-simple-plugin.jar" />
    </fileset>
</cobertura-instrument>
```

Or alternatively, an instrumented classpath with exclusions:

```
<delete file="cobertura.ser" />

<cobertura-instrument todir="${instrumented.dir}">
    <includeClasses regex=".*" />
    <excludeClasses regex=".*\.Test.*" />

    <instrumentationClasspath>
        <path refid="test.classpath" />
        <pathelement location="${test.build}" />
    </instrumentationClasspath>
</cobertura-instrument>
```

I would favour the first approach as it would appear to be a more standard approach.

Comment: I assume that ${classes.dir} is the location of the class files, but i do not have any extracted.I just have the jars & I want to include some classes and exclude others within it.How do I do that?

Comment: @Rami The first example above has such an example. The second fileset is selecting a jar to instrument, called "my-simple-plugin.jar".

Comment: Thanks Mark, both approaches work well. The windows service wrapper I use for my application used to kill the Java app on a service stop, which had an effect on data lost & i was getting 0% coverage.